# Unable to access GCP Compute Engine VM via domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm evaluating Google Cloud Platform to see if I can build a network of applications I need for a project I plan on starting really soon. So far I have the Compute Engine API enabled on my GCP project and a VM instance set up which has Apache installed and ready to serve web pages.

Right now I can only access it through the external IP address. I want to be able to access this VM through a domain name I purchased through Google Domains.

I followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial) to set up domain names, static IPs, DNS configurations, zones, etc.

At the end of the guide, it gives me instructions on how to [verify that my setup is working correctly](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial#step-6:-verify-your-setup) and I've done all of the steps mentioned in the guide (assuming my domain is `domain.com`):

```sh
dig +trace domain.com
```

or

```sh
nslookup domain.com
```

Both of those show the external IP address but when I type the domain name on my browser, it doesn't get resolved to that IP address and I don't see the contents of my VM's web server.

I also went to check for [DNS trails](https://securitytrails.com/dns-trails) and entered the domain name, and it does show the correct records.

---

I'm still looking around for guides and maybe I should have gone with this: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/custom-hostname-vm - when I created my VM instance, I didn't set up a hostname for it, could it be because of that?

---

GCP firewall settings:

[image]

Comment: What is the domain name?

Comment: @MichaelHampton fruitloops.dev

Comment: It times out for me. Check your firewall.

Comment: @MichaelHampton When I installed Apache on the VM, the guide I was using had me do both `sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=http` and `sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=https`. Was I supposed to do more than that?

Comment: Your GCP firewall, not the VM's internal firewall.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've edited the question to include a screenshot of the GCP firewall settings. I don't really know how firewalls work - I'm not much of a network guy.

Comment: OK, that seems reasonable, but does your VM have those tags? If not, then the firewall rules won't apply to it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the only network tag I see on the VM is `http-server`. What else do I need to add? I think this tag was added because I enabled HTTP access but not HTTPS.

Comment: Since you need port 443, you also have to have the tag https-server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've added that tag but I still can't view the page using the domain name. I believe these were the original tags I had on the VM when I created it but since I was having issues I removed HTTPS because it wasn't on the guide I was following. Putting it back didn't fix the issue though.

Comment: Well, now your firewall port is open and it seems to be working fine. I now get a Connection refused. That means now you need to start your web server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton apache is running and I can view the page using the external static IP address I set up for it: 35.235.65.238

Comment: It's not answering on port 443, though. That's where your problem is.

Comment: @MichaelHampton when I installed Apache it was recommended to create virtual hosts, but since it wasn't required I just skipped it. I'll see if I can set those up and get back to you.

Comment: I think you missed something very important: You bought a .dev domain. This domain (and several others) have HSTS enabled for the entire TLD and so require the use of https.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I saw that when I purchased the domain and I do intend to put everything under HTTPS, I'm just evaluating GCP right now so I know that what I plan to do is possible.

Comment: OK, well since your problem is fixed now I've summarized it into an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You bought a .dev domain so you need to have incoming traffic on https (TCP port 443). This domain (and several others) have HSTS enabled for the entire TLD and so require the use of https.

Your GCP firewall shows you have an allow rule for this traffic but only for VMs tagged https-server. Your VM did not have this tag, so giving it this tag will allow port 443 inbound.

At this point you need to set up your web server with a TLS certificate and to answer TLS requests on port 443.